# How do I install a PHP library globally?

Tags: php, include, global, php-7

I'm running PHP 7 on Mac High Sierra with Apache .  How do I install a library so that it is universally available for all my PHP scripts?  I have this line in my test.php file

```
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$tcp = new \React\SocketClient\TcpConnector($loop);
```

The source code (from ReactPHP -- https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/stratum-php)  in question is in a separate project in the directory

```
./vendor/react/event-loop/src/Factory.php
```

I copied the "Factory.php" file to the same directory as my "test.php" file but I still get the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'React\EventLoop\Factory' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/stratum/test.php on line 9
```

Where can I install the missing file to so that it can be universally picked up by all scripts?

**Edit:** I had tried installing the library using composer.  Below is the output.  I don't know where it is installing things but it's not getting picked up by my code ...

```
localhost:react-master davea$ composer global require react/event-loop react/http
Changed current directory to /Users/davea/.composer
Using version ^0.4.3 for react/event-loop
Using version ^0.8.1 for react/http
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 12 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing react/promise (v2.5.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing evenement/evenement (v3.0.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing react/event-loop (v0.4.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing react/stream (v0.7.7): Loading from cache
  - Installing react/promise-stream (v1.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing react/promise-timer (v1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing react/socket (v0.8.9): Loading from cache
  - Installing react/dns (v0.4.12): Loading from cache
  - Installing react/cache (v0.4.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing ringcentral/psr7 (1.2.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing react/http (v0.8.1): Loading from cache
react/event-loop suggests installing ext-libevent (>=0.1.0)
react/event-loop suggests installing ext-event (~1.0)
react/event-loop suggests installing ext-libev (*)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Comment: You cant/shouldn't, instead each "script" should include the lib in its composer.json file, or create your own package which has your desired dependencies and/or additional classes and include that in each of your scripts.

Comment: Did you install the library using composer? Do you require the autoloader file  that composer generates(the file lives under /vendor directory)?

Comment: If you want that particular class then its from the `reactphp/event-loop` package https://github.com/reactphp/event-loop#create

Comment: The library you have chosen can use a psr-4 autoloader: this will include files that follow a particular 1-1 map of class to file-system.  Composer provides an autoloader for you, if you installed that way.  If not you'll likely need register one.  To register and autoload a library across all your scripts/projects is not recommended as you may require different versions per script/projects.  Composer will reduce the complexity of 3rd party library management for you, I recommend you familiarise yourself with it.

Comment: I think you need a preceeding backslash before React to namespace from the root for a fully qualified name.

Comment: @knetsi (and others), I did install via composer.  I included the output in my question.  Although it said it installed, I'm still getting this error so not sure what else I need to do.  The docs don't recommend anything further.

Comment: @dave ok, you installed the libraries. Did you include the autoload file? You should have a line of code that looks like this `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'`

Comment: @knetsi, I had not included that line.  I included it and then got the error, "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'React\SocketClient\TcpConnector' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/stratum/test.php on line 12" so I suspect I didn't build/install one of the components properly?  I'm going to open a separate question for that because I do see a file in my vendor folder, "vendor/react/socket/src/TcpConnector.php".